# use holo theme on Android < 4.0

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-theme

I'm developing an app for Android 2.2 and higher.
I use the great ActionBarSherlock (thank you, Jake Wharton !!) to use the action bar on pre-ICS devices.

While the actionbar looks great, all other gui elements have the look of the default theme of the device (in my case HTC Sense 3).

Is there a possibility to style my (>= Android 2.2) app on all android devices with the Holo.Dark.Theme?

I compile my app with Android 4.0.3, the minSDK version is 8.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Enjoy HoloEverywhere, that's the whole purpose of the project!

(Edit) new adress: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

Comment: buddy contrib doent content any file

Answer (score 5):

No. That would require a back port of the complete Holo theme and styling, which Google chose not to do. It would also be a rather ambitious undertaking and I would think it is out of scope of the ActionBarSherlock project, whose focus is on ActionBar compatibility.

The best you can do is cherry pick the resources you most want from the ICS source and create your own custom theme/styles.