# How to make TextEdit/TextView style similar to Viber

Tags: android

How could I change the style of TextEdit or TextView to make it look like Viber app as shown in below image.

Notice, I'm running this on phone with Android 2.3, so this not just the style of android 4.0 and above.

[image]

Comment: I think you can achieve this using styles, and states.

Comment: thanks ... could you please elaborate more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know whether this counts as an answer, but.

You can use a library like [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) to achieve this.

Check these links on SO as well .

- [use holo theme on Android < 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311988/use-holo-theme-on-android-4-0)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15587723/592025
- [Styling EditText view with shape drawable to look similar to new holographic theme for Android < 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211929/styling-edittext-view-with-shape-drawable-to-look-similar-to-new-holographic-the?lq=1) (The accepted answer to this question should be sufficient for you I guess).

Answer (score 4):

Use this website to generate whatever you want http://android-holo-colors.com/. Because you will put these drawables into your app so it doesn't matter which version you are targeting. Your app will look similar. Cheers.

Comment: This is the one I am using also ... these styles are the base for others as well.