# Android dialog activity with holo light theme

Tags: android, dialog, android-activity, android-theme

I need a dialog activity. So i defined the activity in my Manifest file with:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

but this theme has old Gingerbread look with dark background and so on. I want to complete holo theme on my dialog activity... Is there a theme like Theme.Dialog.Holo.Light ?

Comment: `Theme.Holo.Dialog` and `Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog`.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311988/use-holo-theme-on-android-4-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use under activity tag:

```
<activity 

            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog" >
</activity>
```